# dual boot system .... windows recovery problem!

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have an HP-pavilion g6 laptop with windows 7 installed & there is a recovery partition for it. after I Installed Ubuntu 14.04 (with dual boot) I couldn't recover my windows (when entering the recovery mode I found the restore factory settings option disabled). However I can see the recovery partition in windows & in the grub menu (but not in Linux) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have installed Ubuntu / Ubuntu's boot loader on the recovery partition? This would not remove or rename the partition but format it and write new contents on it?

But no worries, if you can boot into Windows 7, you can [get your product key](http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/) and [download the Windows 7 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). From there on you can create a bootable Windows 7 USB stick ([using this tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and your downloaded ISO) and reinstall Windows 7 at any given time.

After reinstalling Windows, you have to install the appropriate drivers yourself.

**CAUTION!!** When installing Windows after you installed Ubuntu, you will destroy GRUB and will not be able to boot Ubuntu anymore (at least not that easy / without [restoring GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)).

If you cannot get into your Windows 7 anymore, the Windows 7 key can also be found on a sticker on the bottom of your laptop (in most cases).

Comment: What exactly did help with my answer? Maybe this additional information helps others in the future :)